# How to keep column names using AWS DMS with S3 as a target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

After the full load using AWS DMS, the CSV file doesn't contain the colunm names, how can I keep the column names as a part of the CSV file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To keep the column names you need to add an extra attribute in the target endpoint:

```
addColumnName=true;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html